# If the difference between the roots of the equation $x^2+a\cdot x+1=0$ is less than $\sqrt{5}$, then find the set of possible values of a.

Tags: inequality, quadratics

If the difference between the roots of the equation $x^2+a\cdot x+1=0$ is less than $\sqrt{5}$, then find the set of possible values of a.

My attempt is as follows:

$$\left|\frac{\sqrt{D}}{1}\right|<\sqrt{5}$$

Squaring both sides

$$D<5$$
$$a^2-4<5$$
$$a^2-9<0$$
$$(a-3)(a+3)<0$$
$$a\in \left(-3,3\right)$$

But for $a\in \left(-2,2\right)$, D would be negative and $\sqrt{D}$ would be a complex number and in the original equation we are comparing $\left|\sqrt{D}\right|<\sqrt{5}$ and how can we compare a complex number with real no as $\sqrt{D}$ would be complex number if $a\in \left(-2,2\right)$.

So $a\in (-3,-2] \cup [2,-3)$, but my answer is not matching as actual answer is $a\in (-3,3)$.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Just one sign error remaining!

Comment: If you are 'editing' the question to such a degree that is is asking something completely different, it is sensible to ask a new question.

Comment: sorry it was by mistake, I am trying to restore it.

Answer (score 1):

For real values of a I think your answer is right.

Assume other case when it got complex roots then difference is x! . If we take it's magnitude which is $ |x!|=x$ . So here magnitude of difference is $ <\sqrt5$. Now if question is about magnitude of difference then answer [-3,3] is right.

Finally problem is question ,  To get  answer [-3,3] question should have been magnitude of difference of roots is less then $\sqrt{5}$ so that it includes complex roots.

Comment: The OP already got that far, I think.

Comment: please post the final range for a here

Comment: I think you are wrong , please calculate the values of discriminant for $a\in \left(-2,2\right)$

Comment: @user3290550 your solution is correct , I edited my answer see it again.

Comment: see even if they say magnitude of difference of roots is less than $\sqrt{5}$, but we can clearly see that at a=1, D=1-4=-3 , so $\sqrt{D}$ is a complex number, so even then we cannot compare the complex number with $\sqrt{5}$ which is a real no.

Comment: But magnitude of complex number is real number so we can compare it with $\sqrt{5}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited to add:** I misread the question -- see comments below.

---

You have
$$\sqrt{a^2-4}<\sqrt 5$$
This inequality only makes sense if $a^2-4\ge 0$. But you ignored that subtlety when you squared both sides.

For an even simpler example: suppose you have the inequality
$$\sqrt x < 1$$
Squaring both sides will give you
$$x < 1$$
But I hope it is obvious that the correct solution is $$0\le x < 1$$

Comment: please post the final range for a here

Comment: I have already worked out the solution, if you see the post.
But I am saying that $a\in (-3,3)$ is not the correct answer, I have explained my analysis in the post, please review that

Comment: Oh I see -- I had it backwards! I thought the "official" answer was $a\in (-3,-2]\cup[2,3)$. But that was your answer, wasn't it? And you were correct (except for a couple of sign errors -- it's easily done).